# Specific failure assigning grep output to variable in bash script

Tags: grep, variable-assignment

This code block matches some files according the characteristic I'm testing for using the grep expression and outputs the matched portions of those filenames to the screen exactly as I want them to...

```
for filename in "$localpath"*; do
    echo "$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1;
done
```

but I need this data to be assigned to a variable and haven't had any success. This is what I've got...

```
for filename in "$localpath"*; do
    tstring=$("$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1);
    if [ -n "$tstring" ]; then
        .....
    fi
done
```

and this produces output like this where line 25 is the grep line....

```
./numbers.sh: line 25: /home/ben/Desktop/Abe Shows/PhotoSpinner/PC242096.JPG: cannot execute binary file
./numbers.sh: line 25: /home/ben/Desktop/Abe Shows/PhotoSpinner/Photo_080108_002.jpg: cannot execute binary file
./numbers.sh: line 25: /home/ben/Desktop/Abe Shows/PhotoSpinner/purple waving grass w. mask.jpeg: cannot execute binary file
ben@Rowan:~/Desktop/Abe Shows$
```

edit:
I have tried back ticks in place of $(...) but this didn't make any difference.

Thanks for your help,

Ben.

Comment: You miss an `echo` here: `tstring=$("$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1);`  like this: `tstring=$(echo "$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1);`

Comment: Thank you. That works. You are my hero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss an echo here

```
tstring=$("$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1);
```

it should be:

```
tstring=$(echo "$filename" | grep -P -o '[0-9]{4}+' | head -1);
```